# Error: BREAK not allowed in for looping pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I try to create a for looping for my Bubble Sort Algorithm and use break as a condition if there is no more number to be sorted anymore. But then the compiler said that BREAK not allowed. Here is my code

```
Procedure Sort(var data : arr; j : integer);
var
    temp: integer;

begin
    temp := data[j];
    data[j] := data[j + 1];
    data[j + 1] := temp;
end;

Procedure sortDescending(var data : arr; n : integer);
var
    i, j : integer;
    marker : boolean;

begin
    for i := 1 to n do
    marker := false;
    begin
        for j := 1 to n do
        begin
            if(data[j] < data[j + 1]) then
            begin
                Sort(data, j);
                marker := true;
            end;
        end;
        if(marker = false) then
        begin
        break;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: `break` is allowed inside a loop body, therefore the error message is telling you that your use of `break` is not inside a loop. The compiler is correct.

Comment: I think I use it inside the for i loop. What is wrong with my code? How can I solve it if I want to use break so the loop can stop when all the number is sorted.  Thank you before.

Comment: I'm going repeat myself. Your `break` is not inside either loop. I could tell you why but I think it would be better for you to look hard at your code and work it out yourself.

Comment: I found it. I put the marker statement outside the for loop so the break won't work. Thank you T_T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your code.

> ```
> for i := 1 to n do
> marker := false;
> begin
>     for j := 1 to n do
>     begin
>         if(data[j] < data[j + 1]) then
>         begin
>             Sort(data, j);
>             marker := true;
>         end;
>     end;
>     if(marker = false) then
>     begin
>     break;
>     end;
> end;
> ```

Let's add some whitespace after loops and indentation to make the issue clearer.

```
for i := 1 to n do
    marker := false;

begin
    for j := 1 to n do
    begin
        if (data[j] < data[j + 1]) then
        begin
            Sort(data, j);
            marker := true;
        end;
    end;

    if (marker = false) then
    begin
        break;
    end;
end;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
for i := 1 to n do
    marker := false;

for j := 1 to n do
begin
    if (data[j] < data[j + 1]) then
    begin
        Sort(data, j);
        marker := true;
    end;
end;

if (marker = false) then
begin
    break;
end;
```

The `break` is not within a loop.

You likely meant to put `begin` *before* `marker := false;`.

```
for i := 1 to n do
begin
    marker := false;

    for j := 1 to n do
    begin
        if (data[j] < data[j + 1]) then
        begin
            Sort(data, j);
            marker := true;
        end;
    end;

    if (marker = false) then
    begin
        break;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: How can I forgot put the 'begin' after the 1st for loop, hahaha. Thank you so much for correcting my code! ^^